# Exported service Vs ADIL service

Tags: android, service

I cannot find a straight answer as to when to create an ADIL interface in addition to marking a service as exported for use of the service by a remote process.

All I have found so far is that ADIL allows concurrent execution of multiple events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use AIDL when you want to allow other apps or processes to bind to the exported service (e.g., `bindService()`).

If, instead, you are only expecting other apps or processes to start your service via `startService()`, you do not need AIDL.

Comment: I see, so a service marked exported can be started but not manipulated via a binder object from across process boundaries?

Comment: @justanother: Correct. `bindService()` can work without AIDL, but only for a service in your own process. For cross-process work, you need AIDL and the code that the AIDL generates. In principle, you might get `bindService()` to work across processes by examining the code generated by AIDL and trying to replicate that yourself, but I do not know how practical that is.

Comment: `"bindService() can work without AIDL, but only for a service in your own process.  For cross-process work, you need AIDL and the code that the AIDL generates"` not really, you can still use `android.os.Messenger` or any other class that uses   `Binder` protocol (`transact()` / `onTransact()` methods) but i agree AIDL is much simpler

Comment: @pskink: For `Messenger`, you don't even need `bindService()`. Use `startService()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, but it applies to any `Binder`: you dont have to use "bound service" and return the `Binder` from `Service#onBind` - you can pass it via `Intent` used in `startService`

Comment: @pskink: OK, true. But, that approach is fairly low-level and it is not a pattern that I see much in Android. Good to point out, though -- thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare totally agree, its somehow hidden since there is no `Intent#putExtra(String name, IBinder value)` but there is `Bundle#putBinder(String key, IBinder value)`, seems that google wanted not to flaunt with it...

Comment: @CommonsWare BTW passing `IBinder` via `Intent` can be used not only for Binder transactions but also as a "security token" - window manager uses that approach in its "window tokens" http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/07/binders-window-tokens.html